# GnuCash 4.0 displays price as ratio rather than decimal

Tags: gnucash

I recently upgraded to GnuCash 4.0

When I enter a a new transaction into an account that has the columns Buy and Shares, a "Recalculate Transaction" window pops up with three choices: Shares, Price, and Value. I have always left the choice set to "Price". However, with GnuCash 4.0 the price now displays as a fraction rather than a two-digit decimal as in earlier versions of GnuCash.

For example, I entered a transaction of $300.00 resulting in the purchase of 24.691 shares. The price displays as `12 + 3708/24691` instead of a decimal.

Is there any way to get GnuCash to display this as a decimal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## GnuCash 4.2+

Go to `Edit -> Preferences -> Numbers, Date, Time` and under `Numbers` check `Force Prices to display as decimals`.

## Older Versions

Go to `Edit -> Preferences -> General` and under `Numbers` check `Force Prices to display as decimals`.

Comment: As of GnuCash 4.2, the setting is now under `Preferences -> Numbers, Date, Time` rather than `Preferences -> General`.